# Es posible usar un valor de una columna como una condición de un campo calculado?

Tags: sql, sql-server, subconsultas, calculo, formato-condicional

Tengo un query con una columna calculada que el campo flag_valor antes del 01 de Marzo del 2022 su calculo era:

```
Select  
 numero_Cuenta
**,Marca = case when flag_valor = 1 then 'S' else 'N' end,** 
,fecha_formalizacion
from Tabla_Cuenta
where fecha_formalizacion < 20220301
```

Pero después de esa fecha su calculo cambió a solicitud con el campo **bit** :

```
Select
numero_Cuenta
**,Marca = case when flag_valor = 1 and bit = 0 then 'S' else 'N' end**
,fecha_formalizacion
from Tabla_Cuenta
where fecha_formalizacion >= 20220301
```

Como ven la lógica cambió adicionando una variable más.

Existe la posibilidad de crear una tabla de condiciones para columnas calculadas y hacer un join con la tabla que contenga ese campo y hacerlo de una forma dinámica sin tener que modificar el query? Ejemplo:

Tabla de condiciones:

| id | condiciones | fecha_desde | fecha_hasta | sub_condition |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Valor 1 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-02-28 | Marca = case when flag_valor = 1 then ''S'' else ''N'' end |
| 2 | Valor 2 | 2022-03-01 | 9999-01-01 | Marca = case when flag_valor = 1 and bit = 0 then 'S' else 'N' end |

Algo así estoy haciendo:

```
declare @sql varchar(max) = ''

select @sql =   
' 
    select 
     a.numero_cuenta
    ,a.fecha_formalizacion
    ,a.flag_cash
    ,b.pk_categoriaclasificacion_id
    ,'+[Canal]+'
    from dwh_modelo_v2.core.dim_cuenta a
        left join #CAT_CategoriasClasificacionSCD b on a.fk_dim_pais = b.pais and  a.fecha_formalizacion >= b.FechaDesde and a.fecha_formalizacion <= b.fechahasta 
    where 
        a.fk_dim_pais = 506 and
        a.fecha_formalizacion >= 20220228
'
from (select * from #CAT_CategoriasClasificacionSCD) c 
    INNER JOIN (
                select * from #CAT_CategoriasClasificacionSCD
                pivot ( max(filtrocategoria) for Indicador in ([Canal])) pvt 
                ) z on z.pk_categoriaclasificacion_id = c.pk_categoriaclasificacion_id

select @sql

exec (@sql)
```

Pero no me funciona....

Referencia de la tabla:
[image: Creación de la tabla de condiciones]

Comment: Investiga sobre sql dinamico